# Providing an integer as external representation of an object

Tags: python, oop, object, coordinates

I have a family of classes that are composited upon one another.  The innermost leaf of this composition is a Coordinate class that defines the position of its parent Variant class.

I would like to iterate over a list of Coordinates and check if any of the Coordinates are equal to a separate integer coordinate.  I have looked at Python __ methods and I cannot find an exact form of what i wish to do, although __repr__ comes close (but only provides a string form).

Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you need to hash the objects.

Comment: They are already hashed; I can cross reference the coordinates by their memory locations.  However, what I am ultimately doing is scanning across a linear sequence and checking if any of the coordinates fall in that range.  Thus I would like the list of the coordinates to be represented as their start coordinate (an attribute) combined with the reference to the object itself

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [**eq**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) might be more suited to what you want to do. Either that or just create a util function to do the comparison?